# Apps uninstalling on battery death

Tags: applications, battery

I have an HTC Incredible smartphone. Every time the battery dies during normal usage, my applications uninstall. Why does this happen, and how can I prevent it from happening in the future?

Comment: Most of these portable computers will automatic shut down, when the battery drops to a certian voltage, usually that leaves enough power in the system for days of maintaining the volitile memory. If someone change the way it worked (some firmware) , if the battery was really really bad, or much time had passed I could see it.  but It isnt normal. Or I hope it isnt.  How old is your battery, how much did you change the original firmware or software?

Comment: It gives warning, but you can decide to totally run the battery out on some of them. A sort of 911 emergency power last phone call and you don't care if it wipes type function I guess. Did it with a Samsung **ONCE** which was annoying enough to not do it again.

Answer (score 1):

The battery backed memory that holds installed apps is clearing when the battery goes dead. Don't let the battery go totally dead like that. It kills off your battery life, unless you've already damaged it.